# How to get NPM working on Linux

Tags: linux, node.js, npm

I've been using node.js and npm on Windows for some time and everything worked well, untill I tried to do the same thing on linux.

**My goal:**

Use node.js along with npm on linux.

**What I did:**

I downloaded tar.gz file from node.js website and I unpacked it. I have a folder (that unpacked tar.gz) and my guess is that that's it, seems I just need to run "node" file from node.js/bin/ folder to execute javascript files.

I never really thought about what this "npm" really is, on Windows I would simply run cmd from xampp, write npm install  and everything would work fine. I found some link to npm-cli.js file in the same folder where "node" file is. I guess what used to be "npm install ..." now is "node npm install ..." since it's a js file.

I am confused about where exactly packages are supposed to be installed. There are few node_modules folders and when I run node npm install  a progress bar appears and gets stuck right away, nothing happens.

**So I have 2 problems**

- how to get npm working?
- where is this "node_modules" folder?

I've looked some tutorials but there is no "./configure" file, make install etc doesn't work.

I'm new to linux so I'm probably making some obvious mistakes. Can someone explain this to me?

Answer (score 1):

For development on Linux or OSX I suggest using [nvm](https://github.com/creationix/nvm) instead of getting the binaries. Linux and OSX are a bit different from Windows in a sense that you don't always need to *install* programs as the compiled binaries themselves are usually enough.

To install, open a Terminal and paste:

```
curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.31.0/install.sh | bash
```

restart the terminal to make sure you reload the configuration or source your config, then run:

```
nvm install v5.7.0
nvm alias default v5.7.0
```

And you're done!

Comment: Node is throwing out these new versions at a rate of knots. It was only a few days ago I was switching everything over to 5.6.0.  Then this morning we have 5.7.0 appearing.